# Load an image with a relative path using mysql command line

Tags: mysql, flyway

I'm using Flyway to start MYSQL script at the start of my spring project but i'm currently having a problem because i want to load an image into my database using a relative path because my project will be on another server and i want to load the file from Flyway.

The problem is that i can't use the LOAD_FILE function from mysql since it only uses a absolute path.

```
UPDATE table
SET image = LOAD_FILE('/path/to/folder/image.jpg')
WHERE id=1;
```

I'm currently looking for another way to do it, if you have any advice i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: It's possible for a MySQL client program (written in Java, php, python, or some other programming language) to read a binary file like a .jpg and put it into a BLOB column. Flyway suggests "Java migrations" for handling BLOB columns.

Comment: Thanks you very much that's a very good solution

Answer (score 1):

As advised by Jones, i used a Java Based Migration by creating a folder db/migration in my Java folder.

Inside this folder i have a migration with :

```
public void migrate(final Context context) throws Exception {
       Connection con = context.getConnection();
InputStream image = new ClassPathResource("image/image.jpg").getInputStream();

        String requestUpdate = "UPDATE table SET image = ? WHERE id=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatementUpdate = con.prepareStatement(requestUpdate);
        preparedStatementUpdate.setBlob(1, image );
        preparedStatementUpdate.setString(2, "1");
        preparedStatementUpdate.execute();
}
```